# Which activation functions can lead to the vanishing gradient problem?

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, gradient-descent, activation-functions, vanishing-gradient-problem

From this video tutorial [Vanishing Gradient Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIWXbzRXk1I), the sigmoid function and the hyperbolic tangent can produce the vanishing gradient problem.

What other activation functions can lead to the vanishing gradient problem?

Comment: Possibly, the [saturating activation functions](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/gulcehre16.pdf) (i.e. activation functions that squash their input to a finite interval). Both sigmoid and hyperbolic tangents are saturating activation functions.